# how do you read Images into a classifier by Folder name instead of File name?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I am trying to use this script I found online to classify images however I'm not the best with python. The script reads the data in by files name. All the images start with cat or dog. instead id like to make two folders for training and the trainer will know what the images are based on folder name instead of file name.

```
import cv2                 # working with, mainly resizing, images
import numpy as np         # dealing with arrays
import os                  # dealing with directories
from random import shuffle # mixing up or currently ordered data that might lead our network astray in training.
from tqdm import tqdm      # a nice pretty percentage bar for tasks. Thanks to viewer Daniel BA1/4hler for this suggestion

TRAIN_DIR = '/home/connor/Desktop/TensorFlow/SRproj/training_images/train'
TEST_DIR = '/home/connor/Desktop/TensorFlow/SRproj/training_images/test1'
IMG_SIZE = 50
LR = 1e-3

MODEL_NAME = 'dogsvscats-{}-{}.model'.format(LR, '2conv-basic')

def label_img(img):
    word_label = img.split('.')[-3]
    # conversion to one-hot array [cat,dog]
    #                            [much cat, no dog]
    if word_label == 'cat': return [1,0]
    #                             [no cat, very doggo]
    elif word_label == 'dog': return [0,1]
def create_train_data():
    training_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
        label = label_img(img)
        path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR,img)
        img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
        training_data.append([np.array(img),np.array(label)])
    shuffle(training_data)
    np.save('train_data.npy', training_data)
    return training_data
def process_test_data():
    testing_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TEST_DIR)):
        path = os.path.join(TEST_DIR,img)
        img_num = img.split('.')[0]
        img = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
        testing_data.append([np.array(img), img_num])

    shuffle(testing_data)
    np.save('test_data.npy', testing_data)
    return testing_data
train_data = create_train_data()
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing your folders names are thus:

```
 TRAIN_DIRS = ['/path/to/dataset/train/cat', '/path/to/dataset/train/dog']
```

You only need to change your `label_img()` function to parse the image classes from the parent directory instead of the filename:

```python
def label_img(img):
    # Extract parent directory, supposedly the class label, from full path
    #     (e.g. "/path/to/dataset/train/cat/img1.png" --> "cat")
    word_label = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(img))
    # conversion to one-hot array [cat,dog]
    #                            [much cat, no dog]
    if word_label == 'cat': return [1,0]
    #                             [no cat, very doggo]
    elif word_label == 'dog': return [0,1]
```

You also need to change how you loop through your folders / images, e.g. replacing:

```
for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)): # ...
```

by:

```
for dir in tqdm(TRAIN_DIRS):
     for img in tqdm(os.listdir(dir)): # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Im getting this error however with those changes.  TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-40719067ea74> in <module>()
----> 1 train_data = create_train_data()

<ipython-input-67-a4e27498be43> in create_train_data()
      2     training_data = []
      3     for dir in tqdm(TRAIN_DIR):
----> 4         for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
      5             label = label_img(img)
      6             path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR,img)

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found

Comment: You need to adapt your whole code to your file structure. In my example, you would also have to change for instance `path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR, img)` into `path = os.path.join(dir, img)`.